# Timer that continues when App closed and removed from memory

Tags: android

Whats the best way to implement a (Count Down) Timer that continues when app is closed and gets removed from memory?

My current way would be to have the timer in a class that extends `Activity` but this way when the app is deleted from the memory the countdown stops. Is there a way I can get around this?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager) to set an alarm for the desired time your countdown should end.

[This tutorial](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-scheduled-task-example/) is a much better explanation than any code I could put here.